# I want to automate a flash application using flex monkey

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex-monkey

Hi i need solution for how to bring the flex compiler under Eclipse->Project->Properties
I installed FLEX SDK 4.0 and the FLEX MONKEY 5.0
Please find below settings I done to automate a flash application.

- I create a sample project in eclipse project
- created .mxml file under src in eclipse
- Created a new builder under project->properties
- Configured the location and the working directory under
  project->properties- >builders
- Under argument below code is implemented src/application.mxml
  output=bin/application.swf -library-path+=libs/ -target-player=10.0.0
- After configuration, I clicked on ok button .swf file created in the
  location and  the below message I got in the console.
       Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex 4.0\frameworks\flex-
  config.xml
  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex 4.0\bin\demo\bin\application.swf (37942 bytes)
- I opened the FLEX MONKEY click on file->new project
- Configured project directory as : file:///C:/Program%20Files/Adobe/Flex%
  204.0/bin/demo/bin
- Output source directory as : file:///C:/Program%20Files/Adobe/Flex%
  204.0/bin/demo/src
- Suites package name Test Suites
- And I clicked on + button (setup guide)
- FLEX MONKEY status shows NOT CONNECTED
- I installed flex SDK 4.0 so I selected Flex sdk version as 4.0
- Enabled the adope Air
- I dragged the file automate_monkey4.x.swc in to the project libs file
- Since I dint find the flex compiler in my Eclipse and don’t know where to place below code generated in FLEX MONKEY

-include-libraries "../libs/automation_monkey4.x.swc"

"${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_spark.swc"

"${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation.swc"

"${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_agent.swc"

"${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_dmv.swc"

"${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_air.swc"

"${flexlib}/libs/automation/automation_airspark.swc"

- Still I found FLEX MONKEY status shows not connected.

So can anyone please guide me in this like how to connect flex monkey and the eclipse, since

I dint founds the flex compiler in my eclipse.
 And FLEX MONKEY shows like the status is not connected.

Comment: I removed the tag "monkey" and added the tag "Flex-Monkey".

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use flash builder instead of eclipse, and the include command must be added to the compiler settings for the flex project launchin your application.
also, run the app from flashbuilder, and then open the selenium->flexMonkey.
this way it will show as connected.
also, i experienced some problems with firefox 3.6, so upgrade to the latestversion (11)